# Running PHP on 64 bit Windows platform - issues?

Tags: php, windows, iis, windows64

We need to have our PHP application hosted on a 64 bit Windows OS due to another application's requirement. However, reading a bit more on the topic revealed that the PHP implementation is only for a 32 bit environment on Windows.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

> PHP interpreters are available on both
>   32-bit and 64-bit operating systems,
>   but on Microsoft Windows the only
>   official distribution is a 32-bit
>   implementation, requiring Windows
>   32-bit compatibility mode while using
>   Internet Information Services (IIS) on
>   a 64-bit Windows platform. As of PHP
>   5.3.0, experimental 64-bit versions are available for MS Windows.[22]

Would running IIS on 32 bit mode cause potential problems with PHP?

What are the experiences people have had with such a setup?

Comment: I'm really not sure that Wikipedia is up to date, here.  As of 5.3, the best way to run PHP on Windows is via FastCGI, which requires very little integration between PHP and IIS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible Issues:**

http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=14

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/php_64_bit_windows

**Installation:**

http://www.elxis.org/guides/developers-guides/64bit-apache-php-mysql-windows.html